# 3D multi level pyramid

Tags: html, css, 3d

I have an question, Im not sure if it is possible to make **3D multi level pyramid** in CSS and HTML5. There are some Shape generator websites. But there are not compatible with IE and FF.

Eg: http://tt-cc.cc/css3-3d-shape-generator/

https://github.com/imwr/css3-3d-shape-generator

I have also tried with **2D multi level pyramid** but its not fulfill my requirements.

```css
.container1>div:hover {
  border-bottom: 25px lightblue solid !important;
}
#trapezoid11 {
  border-bottom: 25px solid blue;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#trapezoid12 {
  border-bottom: 25px solid green;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#trapezoid13 {
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#trapezoid14 {
  border-bottom: 25px solid blue;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#trapezoid15 {
  border-bottom: 25px solid red;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1 ">
  <div id="trapezoid11"></div>
  <div id="trapezoid12"></div>
  <div id="trapezoid13"></div>
  <div id="trapezoid14"></div>
  <div id="trapezoid15"></div>

</div>
```

**This should be final result** [image]

Comment: That's an awful lot of HTML & CSS where an SVG would be much easier....and scaleable.

Comment: Does the final result need to be exactly per the image or does it also need to be able to rotate as in the link provided?

Comment: thank you all of you to comment. @Shaggy I dont need any animation. but need hover effect only. which is not big issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a single HTML element and a couple of pseudo-elements with gradient backgrounds:

```css
div{
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-7deg);
    transform-origin:50% 0;
    width:200px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
div::before,div::after{
    background-origin:border-box;
    border-top:150px solid #fff;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
div::before{
    background-image:linear-gradient(14deg,transparent 25px,#d00 25px,#d00 calc(25% + 25px),#a50 calc(25% + 25px),#a50 calc(50% + 12px),#fc0 calc(50% + 12px),#fc0 75%,#ff0 75%);
    background-position:2px 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-right:100px solid transparent;
    left:0;
    right:50%;
}
div::after{
    background-image:linear-gradient(-14deg,transparent 25px,#a00 25px,#a00 calc(25% + 25px),#840 calc(25% + 25px),#840 calc(50% + 12px),#da0 calc(50% + 12px),#da0 75%,#dc0 75%);
    background-position:-2px 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-left:100px solid transparent;
    left:50%;
    right:0;
}
html,body{background:#fff;height:100%;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or you can create a "usable" pyramid (one you can actually drop content into) using one of the following methods. You'll need to play around with the padding in each child `div` in order to move the content in from the edges and the content within each `div` will need to be wrapped in tags in order to reset the skewing.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{background:#fff;height:100%;}
#pyramid{
    height:425px;
    left:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 0 25px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) skewy(-5deg);
    width:500px;
}
#pyramid::before,#pyramid::after{
    background-origin:border-box;
    border-top:400px solid #fff;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#pyramid::before{
    border-right:250px solid transparent;
    left:0;
    z-index:5;
}
#pyramid::after{
    border-left:250px solid transparent;
    right:0;
    z-index:5;
}
#pyramid>div{
    height:25%;
    position:relative;
}
#pyramid>div::before,#pyramid>div::after{
    border-top:26px solid;
    bottom:-25px;
    content:"";
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
}
#pyramid>div::before{
    border-left:250px solid transparent;
    left:0;
}
#pyramid>div::after{
    border-right:250px solid transparent;
    right:0;
}
#level1{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#ff0 50%,#dc0 50%);
    z-index:4;
}
#level1::before{
    color:#ff0;
}
#level1::after{
    color:#dc0;
}
#level2{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#fc0 50%,#da0 50%);
    z-index:3;
}
#level2::before{
    color:#fc0;
}
#level2::after{
    color:#da0;
}
#level3{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#a50 50%,#840 50%);
    z-index:2;
}
#level3::before{
    color:#a50;
}
#level3::after{
    color:#840;
}
#level4{
    background:linear-gradient(90deg,#d00 50%,#a00 50%);
    z-index:1;
}
#level4::before{
    color:#d00;
}
#level4::after{
    color:#a00;
}
#pyramid>div>*{
    transform:skewy(5deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="pyramid">
    <div id="level1"></div>
    <div id="level2"></div>
    <div id="level3"></div>
    <div id="level4"></div>
</section>
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html,body{background:#fff;height:100%;}
#pyramid{
    height:425px;
    left:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 0 25px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) skewy(-5deg);
    width:500px;
}
#pyramid::before,#pyramid::after{
    background-origin:border-box;
    border-top:400px solid #fff;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#pyramid::before{
    border-right:250px solid transparent;
    left:0;
    z-index:5;
}
#pyramid::after{
    border-left:250px solid transparent;
    right:0;
    z-index:5;
}
#pyramid>div{
    height:25%;
    position:relative;
}
#pyramid>div::before,#pyramid>div::after{
    content:"";
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
}
#pyramid>div::before{
    border-left:250px solid transparent;
    border-right:250px solid transparent;
    border-top:26px solid;
    bottom:-25px;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#pyramid>div::after{
    border-top:125px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-right:1200px solid transparent;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    z-index:2;
}
#level1{
    background:#ff0;
    z-index:4;
}
#level1::before{
    color:#ff0;
}
#level2{
    background:#fc0;
    z-index:3;
}
#level2::before{
    color:#fc0;
}
#level3{
    background:#a50;
    z-index:2;
}
#level3::before{
    color:#a50;
}
#level4{
    background:#d00;
    z-index:1;
}
#level4::before{
    color:#d00;
}
#pyramid>div>*{
    transform:skewy(5deg);
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<section id="pyramid">
    <div id="level1"></div>
    <div id="level2"></div>
    <div id="level3"></div>
    <div id="level4"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaggy. this can be right answer. but I have checked I can't make other functionality with this. I need to put text in each level. also hover effect. Also it doesn't look too smooth (egdes). I have idea not to make font icon then make it. I will update here once Im done.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple more solutions that make the pyramid "usable" and improves the smoothness. Athough, I haven't (yet) been able to create the diagonal division between the colours of each level.

Comment: Hey @Shaggy you are rock... Rest I can manage it. about size and adding more levels. thnk u